# Master Data Services Web Application Issue

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, master-data-services, master-data-management

I am trying to create a Master Data Service Web Application. So far, I have not succeeded with this activity.

I have check on internet for possible solutions but:

The .NET 3.5 and 4.5 features are checked, the svc file is present, but everytime I run the Master Data Configuration Manager I see the the warning about Internet Information Services.

I do not what else do I need to install or configure. When I try to access the URI of the web application, this does not show anything.

[image]

[image]

[image]

I am using Windows 8 and Sql Server 2014

Comment: copy paste the actual contents of that box. Also expand the Internet Information Services node in windows features. This is a specific features that need to be on or off. For example, from memory I think you have to turn off WebDav.

Answer (score 0):

When this happened to me I discovered I needed to execute the MDS Configuration Manager on the virtual machine's operating system rather than my local machine.

These IIS settings exist on that Windows Server, *not your local machine*.